# it doesn't insert data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to learn php and this is what I created
I only created one file that is index.php and in it is form and connection and insert query. It doesn't insert data in database. Please check if there is any mistake or something that is I am missing?

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Percision Inventory</title>
</head>

<body>  

<h2>Input Machine</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="index.php">  
Serial ID: <input type="text" name="serialId">
<br><br>
Name: <input required type="text" name="name">
<br><br>
Manufacturer: <input type="text" name="manufacturer">
 <br><br>
 Keys: <textarea name="licensekeys" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
<br><br>
 Description: <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
<br><br>
Category: <input type="text" name="category">
<br><br>
Block (A or B): <input type="text" name="block">
<br><br>
Floor (1, 2, Ground): <input type="text" name="floor">
<br><br>
Room: <input type="text" name="room">
<br><br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
<?php

 $servername = "localhos";
$username = "abc";
$password = "dfg";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
 echo "Connected successfully";

  $sql = "INSERT INTO products (serialid, name, manufacturer, licensekeys,        description, categoryname,block, floor, room) VALUES ('".$_POST['serialid']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['manufacturer']."','".$_POST['licensekeys']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_POST['category']."','".$_POST['block']."','".$_POST['floor']."','".$_POST['room']."')";
    if (!$stmt = $con->prepare($sql))
        die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
  ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Connection variable is `$conn` not `$con`

Comment: `$servername = "localhos"` ... this is a strange name, are you sure your server isn't `localhost` with a `t` at the end?

Comment: Nothing. I just submit form and page refreshes but database gets nothing.

Comment: And you are not executing insert query!!

Comment: make it `localhost` ... also setup PHP error reporting

Comment: typo gets deleted many problems here

Comment: It is localhost I accidently deleted t whilst posting this question! Let me check this $conn mistake

Comment: "Connected successfullyQuery failed: (1046) No database selected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your script and it seems that you did not pass the database name. Please follow these code :

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Perform queries
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age)
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code few error. `$servername = "localhos";` should be `$servername = "localhost";`.

In this code you have not mention `database name`.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $yourddb);
```

In your query and form `name` value is incorrect each other: in form you declared `category` but in query its `categoryname`.Its does not make any sense.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (serialid, name, manufacturer, licensekeys,        description, categoryname,block, floor, room) VALUES ('".$_POST['serialid']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['manufacturer']."','".$_POST['licensekeys']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_POST['category']."','".$_POST['block']."','".$_POST['floor']."','".$_POST['room']."')";
```

It can be look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (serialId, name, manufacturer, licensekeys, description, category,block, floor, room) VALUES ('".$_POST['serialId']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['manufacturer']."','".$_POST['licensekeys']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_POST['category']."','".$_POST['block']."','".$_POST['floor']."','".$_POST['room']."')";
```